# MissingUsernameError: No username was given - Unsure where i'm going wrong

Tags: node.js, passport-local

I'm using Node.js with Mongoose and Passport trying to get the user to save to the DB but keep encountering the error where No Username was given. I can get it to save if just using using username and password but as soon as I try to add more fields I get the issue. This is the code I have:

***app.js***

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({    
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  userLevel: {type: Number},
  profileImage: String,
  title: String
});

//ENABLE PASSPORT LOCAL
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
  selectFields: ' firstname lastname username  password userLevel profileImage title'
});

//CREATE NEW model
const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.get('/control', (res, req) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render('control');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
});

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.register(new User(
    {firstname: req.body.firstname},
    {lastname: req.body.lastname},
    {username:req.body.username},
    {userLevel: 1},
    {profileImage:"not set"},
    {title:"not set"}
  ),
  req.body.password,
  (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(req.body.username);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, () =>{
        res.redirect('/control');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! I was using individual objects rather that just the one object :

```
User.register((
    {firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: req.body.lastname,
    username: req.body.username,
    userLevel: 1,
    profileImage:"not set",
    title:"not set"
  }),
    req.body.password,
    (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(req.body.username);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, () =>{
        res.redirect('/control');
      });
    }
  });
});
```